# After amazon ad clicked I can't active cocos2dx keyBackClicked function

Tags: c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, amazon-advertising-api

My game is runing well. And I test amazon ad well too.
But when I put amazon ad to my game. it display strange thing. 
I can't get "keyBackClicked" when tap "back" button after popup amazon ad. 
I think amazon ad got the activity focus. But how can I take it back to cocos2dx.

Answer (score -1):

*In cocos2dx you can use the back Button with 
void HelloWorld::keyBackClicked()
{
    exit(0);
}*

you have to enable this->setKeypadEnabled(true);

Comment: I have setted it true. It just occur after click ad banner then back game.